# Trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 from USB but when booting it shows unknown keyword in 'SYSLINUX configuration file.

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 and I want to install newest version (Ubuntu 12.04). Using start-up disk creator I prepared Ubuntu ISO and saved it into USB but when I boot it it shows an error:

```
'SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 EBIOS Copyright (C) 1994-2008 H. Peter Unknown keyword in configuration file boot:
```

NOTE: I've already tried to open USB drive and open 'SYSLINUX' and delete 'ui' in it.